# InvalidOperationException is ignored in try/catch block

Tags: silverlight-4.0, exception

I have the following coding

```
  try
            {
                var foundCanProperty = properties
                    .First(x => x.Name == "Can" + method.Name);

                var foundOnExecuteMethod = methods
                    .First(x => x.Name == "On" + method.Name);

                var command = new Command(this, foundOnExecuteMethod, foundCanProperty);
                TrySetCommand(foundControl as Control, command);

            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                throw new FatalException("Please check if you have provided all 'On' and 'Can' methods/properties for the view" + View.GetType().FullName, ex);
            }
```

I'd expected that if the methods.First() (in second var statement) throws an InvalidOperationException, I'd be able to catch it. But this seems not be the case (catch block is ignored and the application terminates with the raised exception). If I throw myself an exception of the same type within the try block, it gets caught. Does Linq use multihreading so that the exception is thrown in another thread? Perhaps I make also a stupid error here and just do not see it :(.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Linq's delayed execution strikes again?  Hard to tell from the code.  Pay attention to the call stack of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this isn't an answer, but rather some additional steps for debugging, but does it change anything if you instead try to catch the general type "Exception" instead of the IOE? That may help to isolate if the method is truly throwing an IOE, or if its failure is generating an IOE somewhere else in the stack. Also - assuming this method isn't in main() - is there a way to wrap the call to it in a try/catch and then inspect the behavior at that point in the call flow?

Apologies, too, in that I know very little about the SilverLight development environment so hopefully the suggestions aren't far fetched.

Comment: 'Exception' base class does also not get catched. Yes, try to isolate it later.

Answer (score 0):

InvalidOperationException  exception occures when The source sequence is empty.
refere to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx

check weather "properties" or "methods" is not empty.

out of interest, Why you not using  FirstOrDefault ?

Comment: The exception is correct (by intention). I want to catch it and throw another exception with a description what the developer has to do to resolve the error. It is part of an API